# Как вывести данные на экран без использования кнопки?

Tags: c#, json, .net, xamarin

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout  >
    <Button Text="ccccccc"  />
    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Value" />
    <Label FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"   Text="{Binding Value}" />
    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Detail" />
    <Label FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Detail}" />
</StackLayout>
```

RateInfo.cs

```
      public class Confirmed
      {
         public int value { get; set; }
         public string detail { get; set; }
      }
```

RateViewModel.cs

```
using json_test;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RestApp
{
    public class RateViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int value;
        private string detail;

        public int Value
        {
            get { return value; }
            private set
            {
                this.value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }

        }

        public string Detail
        {
            get { return detail; }
            private set
            {
                detail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Detail");
            }
        }

        public ICommand LoadDataCommand { protected set; get; }

        public RateViewModel()
        {
            this.LoadDataCommand = new Command(LoadData);
        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            string url = "";

            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // выброс исключения, если произошла ошибка

                // десериализация ответа в формате json
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);

                var str = o.SelectToken(@"$.confirmed");
                var rateInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Confirmed>(str.ToString());

                this.Value = rateInfo.value;
                this.Detail = rateInfo.detail;

            }
            catch (Exception )
            { }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, а где у вас тут вообще используется кнопка? Я вижу ее в разметке, но она не задействована. Если вы нам не весь код дали и кнопка вызывает все же `LoadDataCommand`, то подумайте сами, как этот код должен выполниться без кнопки? Вариантов много и какой из них для вас будет правильным - решать вам. Вы можете по таймеру вызывать, можете при инициализации класса, при событие каком либо. Наверно вам нужно по таймеру? Делайте тогда бесконечный цикл, оборачивайте им код в `LoadData`, в конце цикла делайте `await Task.Delay(11);`, все, данные обновляются. Выход только сделать не забудьте.

Comment: извините вот фрагмент кода

Comment: <Button Text="bnt" Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}"  />

Comment: Ну это я понял, мой комментарий выше все еще в силе. Думайте как код должен вызываться без кнопки.

Comment: это то что мне нужно

Comment: но как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте еще раз пожалуйста комментарий выше. `Вариантов много и какой из них для вас будет правильным - решать вам.` ... `Вы можете по таймеру вызывать, можете при инициализации класса, при событие каком либо.`. Что сделать то хотите?

Comment: не использовать кнопку

Comment: при запуске приложения,данные появятся автоматически

Comment: Ну тогда запихивайте в конструктор, после например строки `this.LoadDataCommand = new Command(LoadData);` вызов `LoadData`.

Comment: Как сделать,не могу

Comment: ???????????????